# zero out elements in a list of numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension

Here is a MWE.

I have the following list of numpy arrays.

```
 vectors = [np.array([ 0.       ,  0.8660254,  0.       ]),
 np.array([  1.10501514e-08,   8.64943091e-01,   4.32832253e-02]),
 np.array([  1.34263203e-08,   8.61698881e-01,   8.64582689e-02]),
 np.array([  2.35976215e-08,   8.56300871e-01,   1.29417208e-01]),
 np.array([  1.32175872e-08,   8.48762560e-01,   1.72052683e-01])]
```

**Goal**: For each array in the list I want to set a `zero tolerance` for the values of the array.

**Here is how I did it**.

```
def set_zero(vector):
  ZERO_TOL = 1e-07
  vector[vector <= ZERO_TOL] = 0
  return vector

new_vecs = [set_zero(vector) for vector in vectors]
```

It gives me the intended result.

**Question(s)**: Is there a way to do this without the `set zero` function by using just `list comprehension`?. Something like the following...

**Wishful code**:

```
ZERO_TOL = 1e-07
new_vecs = [vector[vector <= ZERO_TOL] = 0 for vector in vecs]
```

The reason I ask is  the actual array I am working on is thousands of entries long and I'd like optimize my code for this reason.

Comment: When speed is important, why not keeping the whole structure as numpy-array instead of list of arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably what you are after:

```
ZERO_TOL = 1e-07
new_vecs = [np.where(vector <= ZERO_TOL, 0, vector) for vector in vectors]
```

and even nicer following @sascha's suggestion:

```
vectors = np.array([[ 0.       ,  0.8660254,  0.       ],
 [  1.10501514e-08,   8.64943091e-01,   4.32832253e-02],
 [  1.34263203e-08,   8.61698881e-01,   8.64582689e-02],
 [  2.35976215e-08,   8.56300871e-01,   1.29417208e-01],
 [  1.32175872e-08,   8.48762560e-01,   1.72052683e-01]])

ZERO_TOL = 1e-07
new_vecs = np.where(vectors <= ZERO_TOL, 0, vectors)
```

Also note that your `set_zero` function changes the values of your original `vectors`. If this is the behavior you want (I doubt it otherwise why creating a new reference `new_vecs`?) then just do:

```
vectors[vectors <= ZERO_TOL] = 0
```

(assuming you converted your list to a 2d `np.array`)

Comment: for bipolar data you probably want a `np.abs` in there somewhere

Comment: Yes, `vectors[np.abs(vectors) <= ZERO_TOL] = 0` does that. Thanks